# A fluid in a wide tube being centrifuged

Tags: fluid-dynamics, rotation

Imagine a large, awkward and imbalanced centrifuge with the glass test tube in the shape of a large rectangular prism, rotating about one of its ends parallel to the sides. Inside this glass test 'tube' is a quantity of fluid. Mounted to the other end of the test 'tube' is a camera which looks down at the prismical container tube thing.

The centrifuge begins turning at a constant rate. The liquid inside the glass container then travels farthest from the center, inside the camera's vision. What shape will the camera observe? Will the water form a line parallel to the end of the prism, or will it make a circular meniscus?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RauxH.jpg) is an image of the apparatus I am imagining.

A second question would be what if the apparatus had an angular acceleration?

Comment: Depends on the liquid and the expected contact angle with glass - its surface tension. At a constant rate you have virtual gravity so you would expect the surface to behave somewhat similar to the container setting upright on the table in the presence of gravity. I say somewhat because there is gravitational force together with centrifugal force. So it also depends on the angular rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(We'll assume that gravity and surface tension play no role, that the fluid is incompressible, and that angular velocity is constant.)

If you meant to say "cylindrical" (a square patch of) when you said "circular", then you had the right idea.

In the rotating reference frame in which the container is at rest, the fluid experiences a centrifugal force. This force varies only with distance from the axis of rotation, and increases with it.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force#Current_meaning)

Theorem: In equilibrium, the surface of the fluid will be at the same distance from the axis everywhere.

Proof by contradiction: Assume there were two neighboring surface patches of fluid, one of which is slightly closer to the axis of rotation ("higher") than the other. Then, a little bit of fluid from the "higher" patch could gain energy by moving to the "lower" surface patch. Since that conflicts with the notion that the fluid is in equilibrium, the assumption must be wrong. ∎

Since the surface that is everywhere the same distance from a line is a cylinder, the fluid surface must be on a cylinder of a certain radius.

Comment: Thanks! What if there was an angular acceleration?

Comment: http://physics-help.info/physicsguide/mechanics/rotational_kinematics.shtml

With constant angular acceleration, we get ω=ε·t, and see that "Magnitude of total linear acceleration" increases from ε to infinity, while the "Angle between linear acceleration and linear velocity vectors" increases from 0 to 90° at infinity. So, first, the tangential acceleration makes the fluid slosh to one side of the container. With time, the infinitely increasing radial (outward) acceleration dominates, and fluid slowly approaches the same situation as if the angular velocity was constant.

Answer (score 0):

What you have described is called a **forced vortex**. It would be better to position the camera to look at the side of the rectangular container, i.e. looking tangentially. The water surface on a radial line would be a perfect parabola. Depending on the speed, there may not be any fluid left at the centre but the surface would still be parabolic. If, instead you had a cylindrical container, centered about the centre of rotation, the resulting fluid surface would be a parabaloid of revolution.